# Update Highcharts tooltip with onchange

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

I am trying to update the precision of the values in the my Highcharts tooltip based on a number input in the html. I call my JS function onchange of the number, but it doesn't seem to be working. Here's the html:

```
<div id="btnDiv">
        <div align="right">
            Display Precision (1-5)<input type="number" id="precision" min="1" max="5" value=3 onchange="updatePrecision()">
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is the function:

```
    var displayPrecision = document.getElementById("precision").value;

function updatePrecision() {
    displayPrecision = document.getElementById("precision").value;
}
```

Here is the portion of the Highcharts function that sets the tooltip:

```
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, displayPrecision);
            }
```

I know that it's getting the initial value, because it does start at the default precision, however, it doesn't update when I change the number value.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Changed my tooltip code to this:

```
            tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                    Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) +'<br/>'+
                    Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, document.getElementById("precision").value);
            }
```

and got rid of the function. Seems to work just fine.